# Easy SQLite wrappers for Python

Tags: python, sqlite, wrapper

Are there any other SQLite wrappers for Python available, comparable to Rococheting's mySQL wrapper for php?

http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper-v3

If no such thing exists at the time I guess I'll create my own wrapper, but I want to make sure I'm not doing redundant work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SQLite is part of Python standard library since Python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html). The API is similar to your linked PHP MySQL class wrapper (you will be working with modules and functions instead of static class methods).

If you're looking for an alternative API, you can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org). You don't have to use the ORM if you don't need it, you could just use SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language API. As bonus, most of your queries will run in all database backends supported by SQLAlchemy, not just SQLite.

Comment: Support is crappy though.   Many of the great features of using sqlite as an archive format aren't supported in python.   Most notably, lack of blob offsets... which means you can't use sqlite in python as a file archive format... which is a massive use case for sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

See [APSW](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/).